# Remove padding from <figure> inside <header>

Tags: html, css

I am doing an exercise where I have to create a header with an image inside, that refers to the main site when you click on the picture or in the title. I have placed both text an picture inside a `<figure>` tag, but problem is that I have set a `<figure>` style in CSS for other pictures in the page. The style has a padding-top and a padding-bottom value that distorts the alignment of the header.

Can I remove the padding values for the `<figure>` style only inside the header? Here is my code:

```
header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

figure {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<header>
  <figure>
    <a href="../index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x150" />
    </a>
    <h1>Blog de cine</h1>
  </figure>
</header>
```

And this is how I want it to look 
[image: previous applying <figure> style]

But this is the result I get 
[image: when applying styles]

Comment: seems you need to learn CSS more..

Comment: You are so right, I've barely started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's called a *descendant combinator*.

> A **descendant combinator** — typically represented by a single space ( )
>   character in the form of selector₁ selector₂ — combines two selectors
>   such that elements matched by the second selector (selector₂) are
>   selected if they have an ancestor element matching the first selector
>   (selector₁). Selectors that utilize a descendant combinator are called
>   descendant selectors.

Read more about it at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

```css
figure {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg" />
</figure>
</header>

<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg" />
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But what the "0" after "20px" in padding refers to?

Comment: Thanks again, seems a very valuable resource

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS selectors to trace down the `figure` element from the `header` element. Its done using. `header figure`. This means find all the elements which are `figure` inside the `header` element. So write your css rules like below

```
header figure{
  padding:0px;
}
```

**NOTE:** your `header figure` CSS rules get more priority over `figure` rules because the element is selected more precisely. That means `the more selectors you mention, the more specific you write the selectors the more the priority`.

Also this selector will work for you as well in this scenario `header > figure`, This means select all the figure element which are direct child of header element. The above mentioned one `header figure` would match the figure element inside header to any level deep, like you can have 10 divs and then a figure tag in the 10th div and still the CSS will work, But this direct child will work only one level down.

Comment: Thank you so much, great explanation. I will use it for more elements inside my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

CSS chooses more specific rules with precedence. So if you define a more specific rule for your figure inside the header, it will overwrite the other one.

```
header figure {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

You could also add a class or id for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
header figure {
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

to your CSS